Valuation of a fractional ideal of a Krull ring
Let $A$ be a Krull ring, $K= \text{Frac}(A)$, and let $I$ be a fractional ideal. Let $\mathcal{P}$ denote the set of height 1 primes of $A$. Now for each $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathcal{P}$, let $v_\mathfrak{p}$ be the normalized additive valuation of $K$ corresponding to $\mathfrak{p}$.
Then define $v_\mathfrak{p}(I) = \min\{v_\mathfrak{p}(x)\mid x\in I\}$.
It is claimed that this is zero for all but finitely many $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathcal{P}$, can someone offer an insight on why this is so?

What is your definition of Krull ring?

@dummy See here

Ok, using your definition: first for an integral ideal I, due to integrality, for all p, $v_p(I) \ge 0$. Now take a nonzero x in I. Then by definition, away from finitely many p's, vp(x) = 0. Since vp(I) is now squeezed between 0 and vp(x), away from the same set of p's, you would have vp(I) = 0.

Now for a general fractional ideal, take  nonzero c in K such that cI is integral. By definition, vp(cI) = vp(c) + vp(I), and there are only finitely many primes where vp(c) is nonzero. So away from these primes, and those where vp(cI) is nonzero (which is finitely many by last comment), we would have vp(I) = vp(cI) - vp(c) = 0, which proves what you are looking for.
